# Cognos - Only pick one record per month from the records

Tags: cognos

I'm stuck building a query, look at my sample schema

```
Table Name: KRIs
KRI_ID  KRI_Name
------  --------
K1      KNM
K2      KNM2

Table Name: KRIValues
KRIVal_ID  KRIVal_Name  KRI_Value_Date KRIVal_Create_Date   KRI_ID 
---------  -----------  -------------- -------------------  -------
KV1        KVNM1        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 06:01:02  K1
KV2        KVNM2        2016-02-01     2016-02-01 05:12:13  K1
KV3        KVNM3        2016-02-01     2016-02-01 05:20:20  K1
KV4        KVNM4        2016-03-01     2016-03-01 05:10:31  K1
KV5        KVNM5        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 10:09:12  K2
```

Now if we join the PK with FK we will get

```
KRIVal_ID  KRIVal_Name  KRI_Value_Date KRIVal_Create_Date   KRI_ID   KRI_Name 
---------  -----------  -------------- -------------------  -------  --------
KV1        KVNM1        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 06:01:02  K1       KNM
KV2        KVNM2        2016-02-01     2016-02-01 05:12:13  K1       KNM
KV3        KVNM3        2016-02-01     2016-02-01 05:20:20  K1       KNM
KV4        KVNM4        2016-03-01     2016-03-01 05:10:31  K1       KNM
KV5        KVNM5        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 10:09:12  K2       KNM2
```

Now I know I can use rank() to get the latest n records lets say last 3 records per KRI_ID like below

```
KRIVal_ID  KRIVal_Name  KRI_Value_Date KRIVal_Create_Date   KRI_ID   KRI_Name 
---------  -----------  -------------- -------------------  -------  --------
KV1        KVNM1        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 06:01:02  K1       KNM
KV2        KVNM2        2016-02-01     2016-02-01 05:12:13  K1       KNM
KV3        KVNM3        2016-02-01     2016-02-01 05:20:20  K1       KNM
KV5        KVNM5        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 10:09:12  K2       KNM2
```

But I don't want just this I do need last n records but I only need to select one record per month. Like below

```
KRIVal_ID  KRIVal_Name  KRI_Value_Date KRIVal_Create_Date   KRI_ID   KRI_Name 
---------  -----------  -------------- -------------------  -------  --------
KV1        KVNM1        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 06:01:02  K1       KNM
KV3        KVNM3        2016-02-01     2016-02-01 05:20:20  K1       KNM
KV4        KVNM4        2016-03-01     2016-03-01 05:10:31  K1       KNM
KV5        KVNM5        2016-01-01     2016-01-01 10:09:12  K2       KNM2
```

In the above I only select the latest record from 2016-02-01. How can I do this in IBM Cognos Report Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this with a filter and use of the maximum() aggregate function.

I'll demonstrate with a simplified example:

```
KRI_Value_Date | KRIVal_Create_Date | KRI_ID
2016-01-01 | 2016-01-01 06:01:02 | K1 
2016-02-01 | 2016-02-01 05:12:13 | K1
2016-02-01 | 2016-02-01 05:20:20 | K1
2016-01-01 | 2016-01-01 10:09:12 | K2
```

You can add a filter as follows:

```
[KRIVal_Create_Date] = maximum([KRIVal_Create_Date] for [KRI_ID],extract(year,[KRIVal_Create_Date]),extract(month,[KRIVal_Create_Date]))
```

We find the maximum create date for each combination of ID, year and month and only include rows where the date matches that date.

Comment: yes, this could work and is dynamic approach, as I could wait, I split the query into 4 for each month, my number of months is fixed, then got the max for each month and then applied a union on results.